# Show that the following argument is valid by Chain of Reasoning

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I just recently started proving in propositional logic and everything is going well until I came across this problem. I tried to use different methods and it is going me out of nowhere. I read somewhere that the Chain of Reasoning is only used in proving a validity of an argument but not its invalidity. However, I haven't resorted in using other methods of proof to show that the argument is valid or not. Help is much appreciated. Thank You.

> $ [(I \to (J \lor A)) \land \neg(A \lor I) \land (A \to I)] \to J \lor \neg A $

Comment: The only premise you really need is $\neg(A\lor I)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm What do you mean that the only premise I need is ~(A v I). Can you please elaborate further? Thanks

Comment: x @labyrinth: I mean that your goal $J\lor \neg A$ is implied by $\neg(A\lor I)$ alone. You don't need to use any of the other two premises in the proof. (Hint: Use De Morgan's laws to negate $A\lor I$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm By simplifying ¬(A v I) using DeMorgan's Law, I'll get ¬A ∧ ¬I. With that, I could use Simplification which will lead to ¬A and finally, using Conjunction, I could get J ∨ ¬A which is the conclusion. I thought that Chain of Reasoning method requires all the premises to be used in proving. Am I wrong in that one? Thank you.

Comment: x @labyrinth: "Chain of Reasoning" is not a technical term with a generally understood meaning -- it sounds like the particular textbook you're following does give it a technical meaning (which textbook authors can do without asking anyone for permission), but I don't know exactly _what_ that meaning is. That being said: No, logic in general never requires you to use all the premises you have. There are some special-purpose logic systems known as _relevance logics_ (as well as _linear logic_) which do have that requirement, but they are not meant for modeling mainstream mathematical reasoning.

Comment: You're a hero, man!

Comment: In particular it sounds like your logic has a rule called "Simplification", which sounds like it is exactly what you need to justify ignoring a premise you don't care about.